# Intuit - No OpenID endpoint found

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

Where do we find the OpenID endpoint to use in our dev environement/site.  This code is not working:

```
//OpenId Relying Party

OpenIdRelyingParty openid = new OpenIdRelyingParty();

var openIdIdentifier = "https://openid.intuit.com/Indentity-AppName";

IAuthenticationRequest request = openid.CreateRequest(openIdIdentifier);
```

I am getting `No OpenID endpoint found`.  In the code snippet above I am replacing `AppName` with the name of the `DevMaster App Name` shown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you please try the following url

https://openid.intuit.com/openid/xrds

Thanks 
Manas

Comment: Thank you.  That did it.  Can you tell me the difference or why now use https://openid.intuit.com/openid/xrds?

Comment: So should I be using the 2: https://openid.intuit.com/Indentity-AppName AND https://openid.intuit.com/openid/xrds.  If yes, in what order?

Comment: Do you have to use http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1? IF so how to do you force that for the Open Id object? I think this is tied to the endpoint but my OpenID keeps using 1.0. Not sure why